# selecting a random char in a string in java with a certain method

Tags: java, string, random, methods, char

I have to select and return 1 random character out of a string using this method (separate from main method):

public  static  char selectAChar(String s)

I'm not sure how to select the random variable, and not sure if i should use a for loop. everything I've tried I couldn't get it to return the right variable type.

EDIT: heres the coding i have so far

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
    String s = kbd.next();

    selectAChar(s);
}



public  static  char selectAChar(String s)
{


}
```

i tried something using this for loop
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
but i can't figure out how to choose a random character and return it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: would you have to generate the random number and assign it into an int and then use charAt and locate the random int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static char selectAChar(String s){

    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(s.length());
    return s.charAt(index);

}
```

Comment: how would you print out the random character?

Comment: For my unit testing I did...
    String string = "hello world";
    System.out.println(selectAChar(string));
Is that what you mean?

Comment: With your example, you would call System.out.println(selectAChar(s)); in your main method.

Comment: yeah, sorry. i was trying to do that and i just had a typo. thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to generate a random number between 0 and a number (exclusive), one is using a call to [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) the Javadoc reads in part *returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed `int` value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)* and [`String.charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) the Javadoc says (in part) *returns the `char` value at the specified index*.

```
static Random rand = new Random();
public static char selectAChar(String s) {
    return s.charAt(rand.nextInt(s.length()));
}
```

For a second way you might use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) and [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) like

```
public static char selectAChar(String s) {
    return s.toCharArray()[(int) (Math.random() * s.length())];
}
```

And of course, you could use (the somewhat warty) `toCharArray()[int]` and `charAt(int)` with either method.

Since you are returning a value, your caller should save it

```
char ch = selectAChar(s);
```

And then you might format the input `String` and print the random `char` like

```
System.out.printf("'%s' %c%n", s, ch);
```